# Error over year in NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, device

**Real time : 2015-02-17 04:48:06 +0000 

Error time : 1472-02-17 04:48:06 +0000**

Initial dateFormatter

```
 dateFormatter =  NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"
 dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC+07:00")
```

Code Query

```
var dataTimeAddedWithSplit = split(dataTimeAdded){$0 == ","}

    for var i = 0 ; i < dataTimeAddedWithSplit.count ; i++ {
    var predicateTypeActivities : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "timeAdded == %@", dateFormatter.dateFromString(dataTimeAddedWithSplit[i])! )!
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicateTypeActivities
        println(dateFormatter.dateFromString(dataTimeAddedWithSplit[i])!)
```

Help me please T^T 
This problem happen on real device, But I used on IOS simulator not found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wager that the problem is one of locale. 2015-02-17 in the Buddhist calendar is 2558-02-17 (the year is 543 years different). Your 1472 date is coincidentally also off by precisely 543 years (but the other way). It's almost like a 2015 date was read into a device with Buddhist calendar, and then asked to display the date in a Gregorian calendar format. I'm not seeing precisely that pattern in your question, but the year offset suggests something like that happened somewhere along the line.

Bottom line, if you are creating/interpreting date strings for transmission to a web service or storage in a database, it's prudent to use a common format (often a ISO 8601 or RFC 3339 date is used for this purpose) for both reading and writing of the date. In [TN 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html), Apple suggests specifying a `locale` of `en_US_POSIX`.